# How to unittest a function from which you don't know the return values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I have a function which returns a list of values. The values are animals which are in the store.

```
[dog, cat, horse, ...]
```

Now the problem is I don't know the exact values inside the list. These will differ. How can I unittest this function?

This is what I have now but I don't know how / on which values to check?

```
From unittest import TestCase, mock
..

def test_get_in_house_animals(self, ):
    value = self.trade.get_in_house_animals()
    self.assertTrue(value)
```

Can someone explain me the ususal method to use mock data when you don't know the exact return values?

Comment: If all you know is that the function should return a list, then that's all you can test. Mocking the return value of the function under test doesn't accomplish anything, because all you'll be testing is that your mock worked, not the function itself.

Comment: Well, functions with random values are quite hard to test. The only thing available for testing in your case is whether you have a list or not. Where is the data coming from? If it's a server maybe you can mock the data.

Comment: @WillianGaspar it's coming from some API. I can make an example list but don't know how to test against it.

Comment: Could you please show the code of the function you want to test?  Then it is easier to understand how it creates the list, why the content will differ and how to handle that in testing.

Answer (score 0):

In a unit-test environment you mock all dependencies out of your unit.
In your case the e.g. database/repository/api/whatever instance must be mocked in your environment. In unittests it is allowed to test against specific implementation of your unit/boundary context. In this case the datasource. You can check in a test if you call

```
self.trade.get_in_house_animals()
```

that a specific function e.g. `hasBeenCalled('findAll')` which is responsible for the result in get_in_house_animals.

In your case mock the httpClient and assert that your api-enpoint "hasBeenCalled". The result of the endpoint is out of your unit and not part of your unittest.

Hope unit-testing made a bit clearer.